# Is Twitter Bootstrap 3's .container going to have left and right padding?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The bootstrap website and [examples](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/) show .container having [padding-left and padding-right](http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css) of 15px.  Yet, RC2 .container has no padding.  Is this a customization, bug, or intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in the final release of Bootstrap 3.